# iOS - How can I present a full screen controller in iPad as same as iPhone does having curved both the screen presented and behind the presented?

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I've attached reference image. I want to know the 1 or 2 magic lines. I've tried in many ways with different styles but could not able to achieve.

As you can see in below image at Right side iPad screen has presented screen with curved and behind screens moved up side.

[image]

Comment: "in iOS 13.0 or above as same as iPhone"? What does that mean? iOS 13 runs on iPhone. Do you mean in iOS ≥13, the same as in iOS versions <13? And what doesn't work correctly in iOS ≥13.0?

Comment: @DuncanC I've updated question, can you please look?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you wanted to show the presented `viewcontroller` such that the `viewcontroller` should take full screen size as of presenting `viewcontroller`.

If that's the requirement, then you can set `modalPresentationStyle` of presenting `viewcontroller` as `.fullScreen` to achieve that

**Code:**

```
    let secondVC = SecondViewController()
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(secondVC, animated: true) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Janmenjaya as shown in image please see right side image it has curved on top and controllers behind the presented screen moved ahead with top curved. I need that same look. Thank you for your response.